# JBOSS 6-4 EAP installed - cannot access Admin Console

Tags: configuration, jboss, admin

I installed jboss EAP 6.4.

I can reach the Welcome Page but i can't reach the Administration Console from a remote pc.

What i have tried so far:

- starting standalone mode with -b 0.0.0.0
- starting standalone mode with -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
- -starting standalone mode with -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
- starting standalone mode with -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement real ip of management got **"UNABLE TO REDIRECT"** from jboss page
- modify the standalone.xml with 0.0.0.0 on public /management /secure interface
- Verify that the port 9990 is on listening on jboss process
- Verify that exist at least one user on application-users.properties

Jboss start w/o error warning.

What can i try?

Comment: Try binding the management IP specifically with `-bmanagement 10.69.69.69` where 10.69.69.69 is the IP Address of the server - though what you're trying to do should work - actually you could also just try `-bmanagement 0.0.0.0` - it's likely that the management console is only available from the host itself by default through the loopback IP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried the -bmanagement with my 10.69.69 and got unable to redirect (from jboss welcome page).
Also tried bmanagement 0.0.0.0 and cannot display anything

Comment: What happens when you navigate directly to http://10.69.69.69:9990/console/ also check the log files for 9990 and it should show what its bound to and do netstat -ano | grep 9990 (if on linux) and see what its bound to.  Should'n show 0.0.0.0:9990 show show the physical IP Address

Comment: @JGlass changing inside the xml the jboss.bind.address.management with public ip / private ip / 0.0.0.0 it always show 172.x.x.x:9990 on netstat.

tcp 0 0 172.x.x.x.:9990 0.0.0.0:* listen off(0.00/0/0)

Comment: Using the -bmanagement it bound on the new ip that i provide. Just with one combination i get unable to redirect.

Comment: So you have it working at least with one scenario?  IMHO, I'd just use the -bmanagement else things start to get a little messy if you're trying various things.  If you didn't get it working yet, I'd recommend posting your question in the [JBoss Developer Forums](https://developer.jboss.org/) and see if someone there can help you better, also have you thought of switching to JBoss EAP 7?  It's got a lot more features and bug fixes, we're switching all of our apps over to it.

Comment: Thanks again for answer. I think i figure it out, now there is an open ticket on the customer network. 
I'm pretty sure that with the 0.0.0.0 configuration or <any-address/> must works.

Comment: If they help you out, feel free to put it as an answer to your question and accept it as the answer!

Comment: it was a network route problem, ill'close the question and post one answer to resolve the issue if anyone will have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was a network route problem.

Anyway ill' leave here some helpfull trick to resolve the issue if anyone has trouble with it.

First of all, starting properties will overwrite the standalone-full.xml properties.

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=5000
```

Will allow you to start JBOSS and open the public interface to all ip.

The same things can be achieved via standalone-full.xml

in the Interface section modify :

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address: 0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure: 0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
```

and just start jboss without the -b 0.0.0.0.

> Just keep in mind that if the server and PC's that need to remote are
>   on a closed network you don't need to worry about the security.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  On the security, I'd still at least use something other than the default password because if someone (or something (a bot scanner)) got on the network and performed a scan, finger printed the JBoss server and then gained access they could take your application down or put in malicious code.  But again, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help too! :)